# How best to speed up powershell processing time (compare-object)

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script which uses `Compare-Object` to diff/compare a list of MD5 checksum's against each-other ... how can I speed this up? its been running for hours!

```
$diffmd5 = 
(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $localmd5 -DifferenceObject $remotefilehash |
 Where-Object { ($_.SideIndicator -eq '=>') } | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject)
```

Comment: How many are being compared?

Comment: About 50K entries

Comment: This is looking for those MD5 hashes that are in `$remotefilehash` and not in `$localmd5` correct?

Comment: Yep that’s correct @SantiagoSquarzon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) is convenient, but indeed slow; also avoiding the pipeline altogether is important for maximizing performance.

I suggest using a [`[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[T]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.HashSet-1) instance, which supports high-performance lookups in a set of *unordered*<sup>[1]</sup> values:<sup>[2]</sup>

```
# Two sample arrays
$localmd5 = 'Foo1', 'Bar1', 'Baz1'
$remotefilehash = 'foo1', 'bar1', 'bar2', 'baz1', 'more'

# Create a hash set from the local hashes.
# Make lookups case-*insensitive*.
# Note: Strongly typing the input array ([string[]]) is a must.
$localHashSet = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
  [string[]] $localmd5,
  [System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase
)

# Loop over all remote hashes to find those not among the local hashes.
$remotefilehash.Where({ -not $localHashSet.Contains($_) })
```

The above yields collection `'bar2', 'more'`.

Note that if case-*sensitive* lookups are sufficient, which is the default (for string elements), a simple *cast* is sufficient to construct the hash set:

```
$localHashSet = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]] $localmd5
```

Note: Your later feedback states that `$remotefilehash` is a *hashtable*(-like) collection of key-value pairs rather than a collection of mere file-hash *strings*, in which the *keys* store the hash strings. In that case:

- To find just the differing hash *strings* (note the `.Keys` property access to get the array of key values):

  ```
  $remotefilehash.Keys.Where({ -not $localHashSet.Contains($_) })
  ```
- To find those *key-value pairs* whose keys are not in the hash set (note the `.GetEnumerator()` call to enumerate all entries (key-value pairs)):

  ```
  $remotefilehash.GetEnumerator().Where({ -not $localHashSet.Contains($_.Key) })
  ```

---

Alternatively, if the input collections are (a) of the same size and (b) have corresponding elements (that is, element 1 from one collection should be compared to element 1 from the other, and so on), using `Compare-Object` with `-SyncWindow 0`, as shown in [js2010's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67663745/45375), with subsequent `.SideIndicator` filtering may be an option; to speed up the operation, the `-PassThru` switch should be used, which forgoes wrapping the differing objects in `[pscustomobject]` instances (the `.SideIndicator` property is then added as a `NoteProperty` member directly to the differing objects).

---

<sup>[1] There is a related **type for maintaining *sorted* values**, [`System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet[T]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1), but - as of .NET 6 - ***no* built-in type for maintaining values in *input order***, though you can create your own type by deriving from [`[System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection[TKey, TItem]]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.keyedcollection-2)</sup>

<sup>[2] Note that a hash *set* - unlike a hash *table* - has *no values* associated with its entries. A hash set is "all keys", if you will - all it supports is testing for the *presence* of a key == value.</sup>

Comment: If I may ask, is this what is called a method override? You're replacing the default `contains` method with a new case insensitive method? Is it possible to do the same with a new `generic.list`?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon: _override_ refers to class _declarations_, when a derived class (subclass) redefines a method it would otherwise inherit from its base class. _Overload_ refers to variations of a constructor / method with a given name that differ by their set of parameters. The static `::new()` method that PowerShell exposes on types is simply a way to expose that type's _constructors_, to compensate for the fact that PowerShell has no `new` keyword (though calling constructors with the `New-Object` _cmdlet_ is an alternative). In the case at hand, a _constructor overload_ is being called.

Answer (score 2):

By default, compare-object compares every element in the first array with every element in the second array (up to about 2 billion positions), so the order doesn't matter, but large lists would be very slow.  -syncwindow 0 would be much faster but would require matches to be in the same exact positions:

```
Compare-Object $localmd5 $remotefilehash -syncwindow 0
```

As a simple demo of -syncwindow:

```
compare-object 1,2,3 1,3,2 -SyncWindow 0 # not equal

InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
          3 =>
          2 <=
          2 =>
          3 <=


compare-object 1,2,3 1,3,2 -SyncWindow 1  # equal

compare-object 1,2,3 1,2,3 -SyncWindow 0  # equal
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel this should be faster than `Compare-Object`

```
$result = [system.collections.generic.list[string]]::new()

foreach($hash in $remotefilehash)
{
    if(-not($localmd5.contains($hash)))
    {
        $result.Add($hash)
    }
}
```

The problem here is that `.contains` method is case sensitive, I believe all MD5 hashes have uppercase letters but if this was not the case you would need to call the `.toupper()` or `.tolower()` methods to normalize the arrays.

Comment: If case-insensitivity is important, you can use the `-contains` _operator_.

Comment: @mklement0 yes, I was thinking about that, but do you think the operator will be faster than using the method and normalizing? if the operator is more efficient then `-notin` is the best one for this I think but in my experience it is very slow compared with `.contains`

Comment: Yes, `-contains` is slower than `.Contains()`, but that is partly unavoidable, given the extra effort needed for case-_insensitive_ comparison. A direct comparison would be to `-ccontains`, but it too is slower than `.Contains()`, so for case-_sensitive_ comparison you're right: `.Contains()` is better. However, since you can't pass a case-insensitive _comparer_ to `.Contains()`, you'd have to case-normalize _both_ the collection and the string to look for, and that will typically be slower than `-contains`. Note that there's also `-notcontains`, just like there's `-notin`.

Comment: @mklement0 clearly a hashset with `[System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase` as in your answer is the most efficient and best option.

Comment: I think so, yes, but still good to know that `.Contains()` beats `-ccontains` (though in many cases that won't matter).