# PowerShell Select-Object: Using -Unique with First/Last/Skip/Index

Tags: powershell, unique, select-object

I'm just curious if I'm missing any documentation, or if there is a different/better way to do this that negates the need for documentation. Maybe I'm the only one trying to use `Select-Object` to select the `-First X` unique instances from a set of data.

Based on the testing below, it looks like using `Select-Object` with the `-Unique` switch and some type of limiter (`First`, `Last`, `Skip`, `Index`, etc.) inherently causes the limiter to be applied BEFORE removing duplicates. This doesn't make sense to me conceptually, but also doesn't appear to be documented.

I apologize for the poor example, but consider an array of 20 items with each item appearing twice:

```
PS > $array = @() ; 1..10 | % { $array += $_ ; $array += $_ }
PS > $array -Join ','
1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10  ##Displaying the array on a single comma separated line
```

Let's say that someone gives you `$array`, but you can only handle a maximum input of 5 objects. Filtering down what you're given, you might be tempted to use `Select-Object`. At first you end up with 5 objects, but there are duplicates, so quick thinking you simply add the `-Unique` switch and then you realize that the output still isn't quite right.

```
PS > ($array | Select-Object -First 5) -Join ','
1,1,2,2,3  ##5 objects as expected, but with duplicates
PS > ($array | Select-Object -Unique -First 5) -Join ','
1,2,3  ##No duplicates, but less than the expected 5 objects...
```

To get the outcome I was expecting, I'd need `Select-Object` to remove the duplicates prior to returning the final set of objects. While there is nothing wrong in knowing this, it seems strange to me that the `Select-Object` uses the order of operations that it does and also that there isn't any documentation around the fact that the `-Unique` switch is applied at the end of the `cmdlet`.

```
PS > ($array | Select-Object -Unique | Select-Object -First 5) -Join ','
1,2,3,4,5  ##This is my expected outcome, 5 objects returned without any duplicates
```

Comment: I think this has to do with _"When you include a Select-Object command with the First or Index parameters in a command pipeline, PowerShell stops the command that generates the objects as soon as the selected number of objects is generated, even when the command that generates the objects appears before the Select-Object command in the pipeline. To turn off this optimizing behavior, use the Wait parameter."_. I cannot test this now (on mobile), but you could try with the `-Wait` switch if that indeed changes the behavior.

Comment: @Theo, the behavior isn't related to `-Wait`, Instead, `-Unique` modifies the _output_ of `Select-Object`: It is applied to whatever output results from applying the _other_ parameters, such as `-First`.

Comment: Good thought @Theo on `-Wait`, but I actually gave that a shot as well before posting and as @mklement0 says, it isn't related. I just found this to be strange behavior and wanted to make sure it was working the way it seemed, as well as try to document it for others if they run into it.

Comment: The [`Select-Object help topic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) has now been updated with the statement "`Unique` selects values _after_ other filtering parameters are applied." and now also provides a relevant example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, the `-First` / `-Last` / `-Skip` / `-Index` / `-SkipIndex` / `-SkipLast` parameters apply to the original input first, and **`-Unique` is applied to the *resulting output***.

The simple **workaround** is to **use *two* [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) calls**: one that finds the unique objects, and another that selects the desired number from among the unique ones:

```sh
PS> 1, 1, 2, 3 | Select-Object -Unique | Select-Object -First 2
1
2
```

---

Given that **`Select-Object -Unique` is *excessively slow* as of PowerShell 7.2** (see bottom section), here is a **faster workaround**, as you've discovered yourself: Use an aux. [`` System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.HashSet-1) instance combined with [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object); the example also shows support for case-*insensitivity*, which `Select-Object -Unique` currently lacks (see bottom section):

```sh
# Create an aux. hash set that keeps tracks of what objects have
# already been seen, using case-*insensitive* comparisons.
$auxHashSet = [Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
                [StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
              )

# Stream to ForEach-Object, where the aux. hash set is used
# to only pass out objects that haven't previously been seen.
'a', 'A', 'B', 'c' |
  ForEach-Object { if ($auxHashSet.Add($_)) { $_ } } |
    Select-Object -First 2
```

This outputs `'a', 'B'`, as desired. Note that you may want to remove `$auxHashSet` variable so as to (eventually) free its memory - see next.

Using a `-Begin` block with `ForEach-Object`, you can make the pipeline more self-contained, but note that all script blocks run *directly in the caller's scope*, so that `$auxHashSet` is still created there and would live on after the command, so you'll still have to manually remove it and thereby (eventually) release its memory.

- Note: While *in principle* you could do that in an `-End` block, this does *not* work with `Select-Object -First`, because the premature stopping of the pipeline does *not* give upstream cmdlets a chance to run their end blocks - see [GitHub issue #7930](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7930) for a discussion of this surprising behavior.

```sh
'a', 'A', 'B', 'c' |
  ForEach-Object -Begin { 
    $auxHashSet = [Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new([StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) 
  } -Process {
    if ($auxHashSet.Add($_)) { $_ } 
  } |
    Select-Object -First 2
# Remove the aux. variable and (eventually) free its memory.
Remove-Variable auxHashSet
```

---

Note that there's also a **LINQ-based alternative**, via [`[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Distinct()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable.Distinct), but it has important  **constraints**:

- The output is *unordered* i.e. **the input order is *not* guaranteed to be preserved**.
- You **cannot *stream* the method's *input* collection** from a PowerShell command (to pass a PowerShell command's output to a method, it must be collected in full in an array, up front)  - however, the *output* from LINQ methods such as `Distinct()` *is* effectively streaming, due to returning a *lazy enumerable*.<sup>[1]</sup>
- Additionally, **the input array must be *strongly typed***, if it isn't already. PowerShell makes this easy with a cast such as `[int[]]`, but note that with an `[object[]]`-based array as input (which is what regular PowerShell arrays are, such as used for collection command output), but do note that this involves creating a *copy* of the array, which with large input collections can by itself take a while.

```sh
[Linq.Enumerable]::Distinct(
  [string[]] ('a', 'A', 'B', 'c'), 
  [StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
) | Select-Object -First 2
```

This too outputs `'a', 'B'` (though the order of the output elements isn't guaranteed).

If the constraints aren't a concern and you need to find the unique elements in the *whole* input collection (or a large part of it), this solution is considerably faster than the hash-set-assisted `ForEach-Object` solution, especially if your input collection is already strongly typed.

If, within the same constraints, you don't care about the lazy output behavior and just want to get an in-memory collection of all distinct objects - again, *unordered* - you can use a [`` System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.HashSet-1) instance directly:

```sh
[Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
  [string[]] ('a', 'A', 'B', 'c'), 
  [System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
)
```

This outputs `'a', 'B', 'c'`, but notably as a *hash-set object*, not an array, but, due to being enumerable, it'll behave like an array in PowerShell's enumeration contexts, notably in the pipeline.

---

##### `Select-Object -Unique` pitfalls, contrast with `Sort-Object`:

- While the extra `Select-Object` call does add processing overhead, **the command overall has *the potential* to only processes only as many input objects as needed**, i.e. to stop processing once the desired number of unique objects have been found.
- **However, as of PowerShell 7.2, it seems that `Select-Object -Unique` is implemented *inefficiently* and unexpectedly *collects all input first* before producing output**, even though there's no *conceptual* reason to do so: **it *should* be able to produce *streaming* output**, i.e. to - conditionally - output input objects *as they're being received*, because **it only needs to consider what input objects have been received *so far***.

  - In practice, as of as of PowerShell 7.2, **`Select-Object -Unique` is *excessively slow*** with larger input collections; the current, problematic implementation is discussed in GitHub issues [#11221](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11221) and [#7707](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7707).
  - This *conceptual* ability to only consider input received *so far* contrasts with **[`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object)**, which also offers a `-Unique` switch, but ***of necessity* must *collect all input first* before producing output**, because *all* input objects must be considered for proper sorting.

    - As of PowerShell 7.2, `Sort-Object -Unique` is much faster in practice than `Select-Object -Unique`.
  - As for how `Select-Object -Unique` could be implemented in a more efficient, streaming manner: The objects seen *so far* could be stored in a [`` System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.HashSet-1) instance to facilitate an efficient test for whether an input object is considered equal to one that has already been output; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67663212/45375) for a PowerShell example.
- ***If and when* `Select-Object -Unique` is fixed**, the **tradeoff** is as follows:

  - The smaller the proportion of the output objects of interest is to in relation to all input objects, the better off you are using `Select-Object -Unique` (even if you have to *sort* the resulting objects *afterwards*).
  - If you need to output / consider *all* input objects anyway, and assuming that outputting the objects of interest *in sort order* is desired / acceptable, `Sort-Object` is the better choice.
- As of PowerShell 7.2, **`Select-Object -Unique` is unexpectedly case-*sensitive*** for string input, even though PowerShell is normally case-*insensitive* by default - see [GitHub issue #12059](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12059).

---

##### Testing whether a cmdlet produces *streaming* output or *collects all input first*:

Short of examining a cmdlet's [source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), here's a way to test - the *middle* pipeline segment is the command to test:

```sh
# Test Sort-Object -Unique
# Because the command cannot stream, for conceptual reasons, 
# it takes a while for the one and only output object to appear.
1..1e5 | Sort-Object -Unique | Select-Object -First 1
```

```sh
# Test Select-Object -Unique
# The command *could* stream, conceptually speaking, in which case
# the output object would appear right away.
# However, as of PowerShell 7.2, the command isn't implemented
# in a streaming fashion, so it takes a - surprisingly long - while
# for the output object to appear.
# it takes a while for the one and only output object to appear.
1..1e5 | Select-Object -Unique | Select-Object -First 1
```

If the given pipeline above produces its one and only output object *near instantly*, the command of interest is *streaming*; if it *takes a while* before the output object appears, it collects all input first.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @immobile2. If you pass a _.NET_ lazy enumerable - notably as returned by LINQ methods - _and_ the target method is typed as an enumerable, then method calls from PowerShell can perform on-demand enumeration too. However, while the PowerShell pipeline embodies the same concept, it cannot be integrated with such .NET method calls: PowerShell invariably collects a PowerShell command's output in a static array, in full, before passing that to the method.

Comment: The above applies as of PowerShell 7.2. While obtaining a lazy enumerable for a PowerShell command call would be a nice feature, I'm not sure if it would be considered an important enough feature to warrant implementation and I suspect that implementing it would present nontrivial technical challenges.

Comment: @immobile2, indeed, `String.Split()` only accepts static string _arrays_ as input (just execute `'foo'.Split` to see the overloads).

Comment: Yes `.ForEach()` and `.Where()` are provided by PowerShell, as so-called [intrinsic members](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members), but given that they're _methods_, the usual .NET-method rules apply.  Fundamentally, they do enumerate a lazy enumerable as such (though themselves do not produce lazy enumerables). With lazy LINQ enumerables, however, `.Where()` is preempted by a type-native method of the same name. You can call `.ForEach()` on them, however. Use a `foreach` _loop_ if you want to stop enumeration on demand.