# Powershell Remove objects from an array list

Tags: arrays, powershell

Is there a non for-loop way to remove some items from a arrayList?

```
$remotesumerrors = $remoteFiles | Select-String  -Pattern '^[a-f0-9]{32}(  )' -NotMatch
```

I want to remove the output of the above from the $remoteFiles var.. is there some pipe way to remove them?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all of the following:

- you do need the results captured in `$remotesumerrors` separately
- that `$remoteFiles` is a collection of [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances, as output by `Get-ChildItem`, for instance
- it is acceptable to save the result as an invariably *new* collection back to `$remoteFiles`,

you can use the [`.Where()` array *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) as follows (this outperforms a pipeline-based solution based on the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) *cmdlet*):

```sh
# Get the distinct set of the full paths of the files of origin
# from the Select-String results stored in $remotesumerrors
# as a hash set, which allows efficient lookup.
$errorFilePaths = 
  [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]] $remotesumerrors.Path

# Get those file-info objects from $remoteFiles
# whose paths aren't in the list of the paths obtained above.
$remoteFiles = $remoteFiles.Where({ -not $errorFilePaths.Contains($_.FullName) })
```

As an aside:

- Casting a collection to [`[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[T]]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.HashSet-1) is a fast and convenient way to get a set of distinct values (duplicates removed), but note that the resulting hash set's elements are invariably *unordered* and that, with strings, lookups are by default case-*sensitive* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67663212/45375) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If it truly was a [collections.arraylist], you could remove an element by value.  There's also .RemoveAt(), to remove by array index.

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$array = 'a','b','c','d','e'


$array.remove

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
void Remove(System.Object obj)
void IList.Remove(System.Object value)


$array.remove('c')
$array

a
b
d
e
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter the list:

```
$remoteFiles = $remoteFiles |Where-Object { $_ |Select-String -Pattern '^[a-f0-9]{32}(  )' -NotMatch }
```

Comment: hmm they all still seem to be in the remoteFiles var ...

Comment: Nice, though I suggest adding `-Quiet` to optimize the `Select-String` call. Also worth nothing that the result will be an _array_ (or singe file-info object) - though perhaps @Tony actually meant an array when referring to "arrayList" rather than a  [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList) instance, specifically.

Comment: oh how do I do that where with -ne ?

Comment: It might just be a typo, but be aware that if you implement the filter like you did with your original code sample i.e ( $remotesumerrors = $remoteFiles |  etc. } $remoteFiles will remain unchanged because the new filtered arraylist is being saved to "$remotesumerrors".  You'd have to use the same variable name like mathias did in his answer above.

Comment: no I obvi changed the var names - but looks like my new remoteFiles var contains ONLY the errors vs I want the opposite.

Comment: @Tony: `Where-Object { -not ($_ |Select-String -Quiet -NotMatch -Pattern '^[a-f0-9]{32}(  )') }`

Comment: @tony Please output $remoteFiles and paste the results here

Answer (score 0):

Let assume that $remoteFiles is a file object of type System.IO.FileInfo. I also assume that you want to filter based on filename.

```
$remotesumerrors = $remoteFiles.name | Select-String  -Pattern '^[a-f0-9]{32}' -NotMatch
```

What are trying to do with "( )" or what is query that you want to do.

edit: corrected answer based on comment

Comment: [a-f0-9] is totally valid. So is [a-f][0-9]. But they are doing diff things. First one only matches a single character that could be any letter a - f or any num 0-9, your version matches two adjacent characters where the first is a-f and the second is a num 0-9

Comment: @diopside I will give you that but what is "(   )".

Comment: that's a good question. im not sure in this context. ive used something like that in a regex split operation to shift/pad the resulting list based on the presence of spaces in the string, but not sure what its doing here. Ive only used the select-string cmd once so i need to read up on it